# Solr 6.2 represent parent child fields

Tags: json, solr, lucene, solr6

I have a json structure like this:

```
{
    "foo": "123",
    "bar" : {
         "baz" : ["1","2","3"],
         "faz" : "hello"
     }
}
```

Which I am trying to represent in `Solr 6.2` and this schema fails to give me the expected result:

```
<field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="foo" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="bar" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="bar.baz" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="bar.faz" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The resulting schema is this:

```
{
    "foo": "123",
    "bar" : "",
    "bar.baz" : ["1","2","3"],
    "bar.faz" : "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `multivalued=true` for `baz`

dont use bar.baz. just give baz and faz
change these fields

```
<field name="bar.baz" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="bar.faz" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

to

```
<field name="baz" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="faz" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: do you mean multivalued=true for bar?

Comment: for `baz`.  replace two lines as in my answer in you schema file, restart solr. it will work